# Object indices in pandas: Performance? Well supported?

Tags: python, pandas

I "discovered" that I can create a pandas.Index using Python objects, and things seem to work out fine, so long as the objects implement:  `__hash__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__str__`.  Is there a performance hit for doing this?  E.g. will sorting and selecting work as fast as if I used strings or integer index labels?  Is this sort of index well-supported?  Is there documentation about how to do this properly?

Here is an example:

```
class MyObject(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name  # Expect name is a string
    self.complicated_object = lambda x: 2 * x

  def __hash__(self):
    # Allows indexing frames by name rather than question
    return hash(self.name)

  def __str__(self):
    # Makes sure DataFrames print nicely
    return self.name

  def __eq__(self, other):
    # Allows indexing frames by name rather than question
    if isinstance(other, basestring):
      return self.name == other
    else:
      return self.name == other.name

my_series = pd.Series([1, 2], index=[MyObject('cat'), MyObject('dog')])

print my_series

my_series.index[0]
```

This prints

`cat    1
dog    2
dtype: int64
<__main__.MyObject at 0x81a67d0>`

Answer (score 2):

In short: yes, there will be a performance hit for sorting. Here's a test case:

```
n = 10000
idx = np.random.permutation(n)
data = np.arange(n)
obj_idx = [MyObject(str(ii)) for ii in idx]
str_idx = [str(ii) for ii in idx]
int_idx = idx.tolist()

s1 = pd.Series(data, obj_idx)
s2 = pd.Series(data, str_idx)
s3 = pd.Series(data, int_idx)
```

Sort times:

```
In [1]: %%timeit s = s1.copy()
s.sort_index()
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 47.6 ms per loop

In [2]: %%timeit s = s2.copy()
s.sort_index()
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.63 ms per loop

In [3]: %%timeit s = s3.copy()
s.sort_index()
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 794 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I get 5x slowdown with n = 1M.  I tried defining __lt__ (and other comparisons) and the slowdown is still 5x.  I also tried copy by itself, and no slowdown, so that's good.

Comment: Note that I edited the question to also ask if these "object" indices are well supported...e.g. is there documentation about how to make one that will work in the future?